# AngularJS: Bind service properties to controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've just started with ngJS.

I've found the way to bind the service `objects` to controllers.

I would like to know that, is this the good practice to achieve this or there is a recommended way to do this?

I would also like to know why is this possible only on `objects` and not `properties`?

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0j0mdjco/).
In depth explanations are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value).

> A `variable` can hold one of two types of values: `primitive values
>   and reference values`.
>
> - `Primitive values` are data that are stored on the **stack**.
> - `Primitive value` is stored directly in the location that the variable accesses.
> - `Reference values` are **objects** that are stored in the **heap**.
> - `Reference value` stored in the variable location is a pointer to a location in memory where the object is stored.
> - Primitive types inlcude `Undefined`, `Null`, `Boolean`, `Number`, or `String`.
>
> **The basics**
>
> Objects are aggregations of properties. A property can reference an
>   `object` or a `primitive`. `Primitives are values`, they have no
>   properties.
>
> JavaScript has 5 primitive datatypes: **string,** **number**,
>   **boolean**, **null**, **undefined**. With the exception of null and undefined, all primitives values have object equivalents which wrap
>   around the primitive values, e.g. a **String** object wraps around a
>   string primitive. All primitives are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you bound only scope properties to the view and then these properties have been initialized with service properties values.
Your code with some edits:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('s1', function() {
    this.Input = {
        name: 'John'
    };

    this.name = 'Doe';
});

myApp.controller('c1', function($scope, s1) {
    $scope.Input = s1.Input;
    $scope.name = s1.name;
});

myApp.controller('c2', function($scope, s1) {
    $scope.Input = s1.Input;
    $scope.name = s1.name;

    $scope.change = function() {
        console.log("s1.name = "+s1.name);
        s1.name = "ciao";
        console.log("s1.name = "+s1.name);
    };
});
```

So if you change the value of $scope.name of the c2 controller (for example editing the input box in the view) that doesn't propagate to s1.name.
And more, if you change the s1.name property (see $scope.change method in c2 controller) this modification is not propagated to $scope.name.

A way to propagate changes in service properties is using events, that is rising events from service and listening the same events in the controllers (see [How do I create a custom event in an AngularJs service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129710/how-do-i-create-a-custom-event-in-an-angularjs-service)).

Here is the jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/0j0mdjco/2/